# Incorrect time difference

Tags: php, time

Why is the output of the below code negative?

**Code:**

```
$date=strtotime("2013-04-10 21:31:30");
$now=time();
$diff=$now-$date;
echo $diff;
```

Above code's output is `-17295`

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't `$date > $now`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting negative answer as  the time `2013-04-10 21:31:30` , that you are assigning to `$date` PHP Variable is an **Indian standard time**.

Your server time zone may not be  **Asia/Calcutta**.So you need to Set the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script to **Asia/Calcutta** using **[date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)** function.

This should work perfectly: **[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/rW12aq)**

```
<?php
$date=strtotime("2013-04-10 21:31:30");
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) 
                                date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
$now=time();
$diff=$now-$date;
echo $diff;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you subtract something bigger (`strtotime("2013-04-10 21:31:30")`) from something smaller (`$date`)

But it also may be because you haven't set the timezone or it is not set properly in PHP, if `$now` is really greater than `$date`

Comment: Thanks, this will be reason.

Answer (score 1):

because the timestamp of $date is in the future and therefore $now is less than it, thus producing a negative number

Answer (score 0):

If we are `1365612708` seconds from Jan 1st 1970 and tonight at 21:31:30 is `1365625890` seconds from jan 1st 1970 when you subtract now (`1365612708`) from the specified time tonight (`1365625890`) you get `-13182` seconds (which is 3.6 hours (aka 3 hours 30 mins (ish)) in the future)